# Average Case Complexity of a trivial algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, average

```
P(x,y,z){
    print x
    if(y!=x) print y
    if(z!=x && z!=y) print z
}
```

Trivial Algorithm here, values `x`,`y`,`z` are chosen randomly from `{1,...r}` with `r >= 1`.
I'm trying to determine the average case complexity of this algorithm and I measure complexity based on the number of print statements.

The best case here is T(n) = 1 or O(1), when `x=y=z` and the probability of that is 1/3.
The worst case here is still T(n) = 3 or still O(1) when `x!=y!=z` and the probability is 2/3.

But when it comes to mathematically deriving the average case:
Sample Space is n possible inputs, Probability over Sample Space is 1/n chance
So, how do I calculate average case complexity? (This is where I draw a blank..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has three cases:

1. All three numbers are equal. The probability of this is *1/r*, since
   once you choose *x*, there's only one choice for *y* and for *z*. The cost
   for this case is 1.
2. *x != y*, but *x == z* or *y == z*. The probability of this is 1/r * (1/(r - 1))* 1/2, 
   since once you choose x, you only have r -1 choices left for y, and z can only be 
   one of these two choices. Cost  = 2.
3. All three numbers are distinct. Probability that all three are distinct is 
   1/r * (1/(r - 1))*(1/(r - 2)). Cost = 3.

Thus, the average case can be computed as:

```
1/r  + 1/r * (1/(r - 1)) + 1/r * (1/(r - 1))*(1/(r - 2)) * 3 == O(1)
```

**Edit:** The above expression is *O(1)*, since the whole expression is made up of constants.

Comment: I know the complexity has to be O(1), but how do you arrive at that from the equation above?

Comment: @spacker_lechuck: The whole expression is made up of constants. That's why it's O(1).

Answer (score 0):

The average case will be somewhere between the best and worst cases; for this particular problem, that's all you need (at least as far as big-O).

Answer (score 0):

1)  Can you program the general case at least?  Write the (pseudo)-code and analyze it, it might be readily apparent.  You may actually program it suboptimally and there may exist a better solution.  This is very typical and it's part of the puzzle-solving of the mathematics end of computer science, e.g. it's hard to discover quicksort on your own if you're just trying to code up a sort.

2)  If you can, then run a monte carlo simulation and graph the results.  i.e., for N = 1, 5, 10, 20, ..., 100, 1000, or whatever sample is realistic, run 10000 trials and plot the average time.  If you're lucky X = sample size, Y = avg. time for 10000 runs at that sample size will graph out a nice line, or parabola, or some easy-to-model curve.

So I'm not sure if you need help on (1) finding or coding the algorithm or (2) analyzing it, you will probably want to revise your question to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

```
P(x,y,z){
   1.print x
   2.if(y!=x)
   3. print y
   4.if(z!=x && z!=y)
   5.  print z
}
```

Line 1: takes a constant time **c1** (c1:print x)

Line 2: takes a constant time **c2** (c2:condition test)

Line 3 :takes a constant time **c3** (c3 :print y)

Line 3: takes a constant time **c4** (c4:condition test)

Line 4: takes a constant time **c5**  (c5:print z)

**Analysis :**

Unless your function P(x,y,z) does not depend on input size " r" the  program will take a constant amount of time to run since **Time Taken :T(c1)+T(c2+c3)+T(c4+c5)** ..summing up the Big O of the function P(x,y,z) is **O(1)** where 1 is a constant and indicates constant amount of time since T(c1),T(c2),..T(c5) all take constant amount of time.. and say if the function P(x,y,z) iterates from 1 to r..then the complexity of your snippet would have changed and will be in terms of  the input size i.e "r"

Best Case     :    O(1)

Average Case  :    O(1)

worst Case    :    O(1)